# What is this "magic circle" in Castlevania: Dawn of Sorrow?

Tags: castlevania-dawn-of-sorrow

While I was farming for Alamaric Sniper and Ghost Dancer souls, I had something happen where it looked like a Sniper was going to give me a soul, but I didn't actually get one. Instead, this red magic circle-looking thing was left behind in the air for a few seconds, along with a pair of wings. Eventually, the wings disappeared, and the circle expanded and faded away.

[image: Mysterious red magic circle with wings]

[image: Mysterious red magic circle without wings]

[image: Mysterious red magic circle fading away]

I only had 7 Sniper souls at the time, so it wasn't that I was maxed out. I've tried researching it myself, but searches about "magic circle" tend to lead to Magic Seals, and searches about souls not dropping tend to lead to complaints about drop rates, so I haven't had any luck. If it matters, I'm playing on DeSmuME 0.9.7.

Is this an actual part of the game, or just a glitch of some sort?

---

In response to the Arc Demon suggestion: I've found a Dawn of Sorrow Arc Demon sprite sheet on [this site](http://www.castlevaniacrypt.com/dos/sprites). While they also use red magic circles, the designs aren't very similar, so I'm afraid that can't be it. Among other things, this circle has a star in the center, while the Arc Demon one does not.

[image: Comparison of magic circles]

Comment: Do you still have your copy of the game? Alamaric Sniper Sprite Sheet does show the magic circle. My guess is that it's an attack that it rarely uses. Keep a sniper alive for a while to see if it does anything new?
https://www.castlevaniacrypt.com/wp-content/img/dos/sprites/amalaric-sniper.png

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a glitch. Arch Demons and other enemies use this sprite when spawning and attacking, so the game may have loaded the wrong sprite. [Here](http://castlevania.wikia.com/wiki/Amalaric_Sniper) is the link.

[image: arc demon spawning]

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: [http://castlevania.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_Demon] here is a link to the page. The section "dawn of sorrow" explains that arc demons 'summon magic seals to summon fire balls to attack'  I can't remember the other enemies that use the 'magic seals' right now.

Comment: [http://castlevania.wikia.com/wiki/Amalaric_Sniper] this page doesn't state of any intent of this of this, so it probably wasn't, therefore it being a bug/glitch

Comment: This sounds promising. Could you edit the above information into your answer and provide a picture of the magic seal of the Arc Demon (or other enemy as appropriate) for comparison purposes?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be it. I've updated my question with clearer pictures and a comparison.

Comment: @Michaellogg, The only thing I could think of is it is an unused sprite  and was displayed thru a glitch/bug